# How to add Listeners to multiple JButtons, from a view and controller, using reflection?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, reflection

I'm having some difficulty implementing the **MVC pattern** using **reflection**.

I have the **Model**. **I know nothing about this model**. And I'm inferring with reflection;

I also have a **View**; This view will instantiate a **list of objects** ( JButton , JTextField , and others, ...) and also has a method to add listeners to buttons, that in turn, will invoke methods on my controller.

Then I have the **controller** that implements an ActionListener.

All good so far, it works... I can set the buttons programmatically , add listeners, execute methods on the controller and ask the controller to update the model, I believe I'm on the right track with MVC. However, I'm trying to do this with reflection.

E.g: I go to the **Model** from the **Controller**. I pick a given class (again, I know nothing about this class) and get ALL the setters of the class.

Then I ask the **View** to create a series of JTextFields (if that's the case), for all my setters, with a Save button to later on perform the setter from an **action listener**.

If I get 2 setters, the view creates 2 JTextFields and 2 save buttons. But how do I know, what button was pressed? In other words, how would I know what setter that button belongs to? Normally, this wouldn't be a problem, but like I said, I know nothing about the **Model**, so the **View** will might create 1, 2, 3, or a gazillion of buttons with JTextFields, JButtons and so on, ...

I'm developing a Naked Objects framework for a class project. So when I say I know nothing about the Model, is because I'm creating a GUI, based on any Model that might exist. Thus creating me some problems relating my buttons, text fields, lists in my View, to my the methods that need to be executed.

All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Create controls inheriting from the specific JControl and add the state you need there. Then on the listener cast the control to your control class.

Comment: What I'm getting is, save state in a control that is managed by the View. I'm having trouble understanding how that would help me. Could you be more specific? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you have to distinguish two buttons is by adding state that you know that will be there when the listener you registred fires. Earlier, in my comment, I suggested that you could inherit from the control and add your state there.

```
public class MyButton extends JButton{
    private Runnable onActionPerfomed;

    public Runnable getMyAction(){
        return onActionPerfomed;
    }

    public void setMyAction(Runnable r){
        onActionPerfomed = r;
    }
}

final MyButton button = new MyButton();
button.setName("button xpto");
button.setMyAction(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hey I'm running this on button " + button.getName());
    }
});

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() instanceof MyButton){
            MyButton btn = (MyButton)e.getSource();
            btn.getMyAction().run();
        }
    }
});
```

You can achieve a effect like this one by making the Controls implement a interface instead which is more advisable.
**Finally** Why register the same listener for all Controls? I think that you really should register different listeners because that is what the code I provided does in a different way.